# SQL : What does column <> '*.*' mean?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an existing code where I found below where condition on a table.

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE MYCOLUMN <> '*.*';
```

Is there a difference between `MYCOLUMN <> '*.*'` and `MYCOLUMN <> '*'`;

What does `MYCOLUMN <> '*.*'` mean?

Comment: Not equals comparison (`<>`) has no wildcards. I.e `not equal to *.*`, or `not equal to *`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a difference between `MYCOLUMN <> '*.*'` and `MYCOLUMN <> '*'`

Yes, you are comparing different text literals with [an inequality comparison condition](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Comparison-Conditions.html#GUID-828576BF-E606-4EA6-B94B-BFF48B67F927).

The `*` has no special meaning. Specifically it is **not** a wildcard. From the patterns it looks like *maybe* your column holds filenames and you're doing some processing with the values later at OS level, where they might be wildcards. To the actual query they are not though.

The `<>` is the same as `!=`, so you  are looking for either for rows where the entire content of the column is *not* the literal string `'*.*'` in the first case, or where the entire content of the column is not the literal string `'*'` in the second. No value can ever match both of those conditions, except null.  (And null doesn't really match either - as it isn't equal to *or* not equal to anything; but the result of the comparison is 'unknown' so it isn't included in the result set).

As a demo:

```
create table t42(id number, mycolumn varchar2(20));
insert into t42 (id, mycolumn) values (1, '*');
insert into t42 (id, mycolumn) values (2, 'The*is embedded');
insert into t42 (id, mycolumn) values (3, 'The * is embedded');
insert into t42 (id, mycolumn) values (4, '*.*');
insert into t42 (id, mycolumn) values (5, 'The*.*is embedded');
insert into t42 (id, mycolumn) values (6, 'The *.* is embedded');
insert into t42 (id, mycolumn) values (7, 'No asterisk');
insert into t42 (id, mycolumn) values (8, null);
```

With the first condition only IDs 3 and 8 are excluded (3 because the condition is true, 8 because it is unknown):

```
select * from t42 where MYCOLUMN <> '*.*';

        ID MYCOLUMN            
---------- --------------------
         1 *                   
         2 The*is embedded     
         3 The * is embedded   
         5 The*.*is embedded   
         6 The *.* is embedded 
         7 No asterisk         

6 rows selected.
```

With the second condition only IDs 1 and 8 are excluded:

```
select * from t42 where MYCOLUMN <> '*';

        ID MYCOLUMN            
---------- --------------------
         2 The*is embedded     
         3 The * is embedded   
         4 *.*                 
         5 The*.*is embedded   
         6 The *.* is embedded 
         7 No asterisk         

6 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 4):

> What does `MYCOLUMN <> '*.*'` mean?

If the value in `MYCOLUMN` is not the exact string `'*.*'` and is not `NULL` then it will be matched by that condition.

`*` is not a wildcard character.

> Is there a difference between `MYCOLUMN <> '*.*'` and `MYCOLUMN <> '*'`?

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e9c9f/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**: Some test data:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( mycolumn ) AS
SELECT '*' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '*.*' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'a.b' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'a' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT NULL FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  MYCOLUMN <> '*.*'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e9c9f/1/0)**: Matches all the rows that are not identical to `'*.*'` or `NULL`.

```
| MYCOLUMN |
|----------|
|        * |
|      a.b |
|        a |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  MYCOLUMN <> '*'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e9c9f/1/1)**: Matches all the rows that are not identical to `'*'` or `NULL`.

```
| MYCOLUMN |
|----------|
|      *.* |
|      a.b |
|        a |
```

**Query 3**: If you want to use wildcards in a match then use the `LIKE` operator with `%` as the wildcard (instead of `*`).

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  MYCOLUMN NOT LIKE '%.%'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e9c9f/1/2)**: Matches all the values that are not `NULL` and do not contain a `.` character:

```
| MYCOLUMN |
|----------|
|        * |
|        a |
```

**Query 4**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  MYCOLUMN NOT LIKE '%'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e9c9f/1/3)**:  Matches all the values that are not `NULL` and do not contain zero-or-more characters (this will never match anything).

```
No data found.
```

Answer (score 0):

The where condition

```
MYCOLUMN <> '*.*'
```

is searching specifically for text diferent from `'*.*'`. This search will include `'*'` because `'*'` is different from `'*.*'`.

The where condition isn't checking regular expressions or wildcards.

To search text looking for text with `*` you can use the like condition - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/conditions016.htm.

Comment: `LIKE` does not use the `*` character as a wildcard. Also, if you are going to link to documentation, please link to official Oracle documentation rather than 3rd party documentation that is quite often not Oracle specific.

Comment: You're right, my bad! Edited my answer to link to the oracle docs. Ty